# Как нажать на специальный символ в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Добырй день, посдкажите как нажать на символ **+** не понимаю, если выбираю категорию то все окей, а мне надо именно расскрыть подкатегории
Вот [Ссылка](https://spb.vseinstrumenti.ru/category/santehnicheskoe-oborudovanie-6750/) на сайт на котором пытаюсь сделать

**Вот код который выполняю**

```
driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(version_main=108)
driver.get('https://vseinstrumenti.ru/category/santehnicheskoe-oborudovanie-6750/')
time.sleep(3)
cat = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH('//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')).click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

**Вот ошибка которую получаю**

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
    cat = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH('//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')).click()
```

Вот как мне правильно реализовать нажатие на вот этот символ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кст, а `.click()` что-то возвращает, а то у вас выражение `cat = driver.find_elements(...).click()` и я думаю, что тут в `cat` у вас всегда будет `None`

Comment: @gil9red, тут это не причем, я пробовал и без переменной cat, все равно ошибка остается.

Comment: Приложите в вопросу кусок кода где тот элемент находится. Потому что, наверняка у него есть какой-то атрибут за который можно уцепится, т.к.  путь `//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]` какая-то шляпа, это не поддерживать нормально и сломается при малейшем изменении любого из тегов пути (типа таких путей: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/429f4127afa676364613b45d3dfca428d64eb102/html_parsing/the_most_profitable_dish__sushivkusno.com.py#L67)

Comment: Кст, а почему вы используете `find_elements`, когда нужно получить 1 элемент. Он вам список вернет. Вам нужно использовать `find_element`

Comment: Я вчера смог решить вопрос, заметил что когда идет запрос через браузер отрабатывает js сайта и он в коде страницы сразу отображает все вложенные подкатегории, а когда делаешь обычный GET запрос с парсера то этого куска нет. Ну я просто открыл браузер и через PAGE_SOURCE забрал их. Спасибо что пытались помочь!

Comment: Пожалуйста :), если мой ответ был полезен [проголосуйте по нему и примите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Метод [find_elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) принимает 2 параметра: способ поиска (`str`) и строку поиска

У вас способ поиска был использован как функция, поэтому ошибка:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Правильно так:

```
cat = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]').click()
```

Comment: не отрабатывает(( ошибка точно такая же

Comment: @Ruin, вы написали про ошибку, я написал в чем причина ее. То, что у вас не тыкает это другой вопрос :)